# How to change the source attribute of an image tag with jquery onclick?

Tags: jquery, image, onclick, attributes

I know this is a really simple thing but I tried some solutions from other posts and they seemed to be outdated. I also used an example from the current jquery api documentation and that did not work either. I am working on a chrome extension with a linked js file. There appears to be no errors or messages in the console when I test the onclick function, but the image attribute does not seem to change. I know the js file is connected properly because I am using the same script to generate the header of the chrome extension. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please show us what code you have tried so far along with your HTML structure of Images?

Comment: Seems to be working fine - [codepen](https://codepen.io/fen1x/pen/eVdxQO?editors=1010)

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

According to your question's title its really very simple.
I assume you have something to click and on click source of image tag should be change.

```
 <div>
    <input type="button" id="btnChangeImageSource" value="Change Source">
   <img src="" height="100" width="100" id="targetTag"> 
 </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

     $('#btnChangeImageSource').click(function(){

      $('#targetTag').attr('src','new source ')

    });
  });
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks! I think my problem was that I didn't have the $(document).ready part. Can someone explain why that's necessary?

Comment: see this for more clarification. https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_ready.asp